# Keep getting syntax error. What do I need to do?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, arguments, sum

I am trying to get my function to take two arguments, and return their sum. Am I going about this the right way? This is what I have so far:

```
def my_sum(a, b):
    sum = a + b

def main():
    a = input(int("enter a number: ", a)
    b = input(int("enter a number: ", b)

    sum = a + b

    return sum
    print(" result: ", sum)

main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it looks good, but the main problem is that you aren't actually calling your function :) Once you get your two numbers, you can then make the call to your function (which you have properly set up):

```
def main():
    # When you assign variables here, make sure you are putting the int outside
    # You also don't need to reference the variable twice
    a = int(input("enter a number: "))
    b = int(input("enter a number: "))

    # Here is where your call goes (try to avoid using variable names that
    # are the same as Python keywords, such as sum)
    s = my_sum(a, b)

    print(" result: ", s)
```

Now, one other thing you'll have to do is modify your function to return a value. You're already almost there - just add a return (note that since you are just returning the sum of the two numbers, you don't have to assign it to a variable):

```
def my_sum(a, b):
    return a + b
```

This now means that when you run `s = my_sum(a, b)`, your function will return the sum of those two numbers and put them into `s`, which you can then print as you are doing.

One other minor thing - when you use the setup you are (with `def main()`, etc.), you usually want to call it like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

At this stage, don't worry too much about what it means, but it is a good habit to get into once you start getting into fun stuff like modules, etc. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. doing a `print` function after `return sum` won't work because when returning a return value, the execution will exit the scope, the orders should be reversed.
2. your input function is not implemented correctly.

The correct code should be:

```
def main():

    a = input("enter a number: ")
    b = input("enter a number: ")
    sum = a + b    
    print(" result: ", sum)    
    return sum
```

Comment: Rolled back the edit. This is flagged with Python 3. The original was correct.

Answer (score 0):

You Have written Wrong coding Style
If you want to do some by using sum method than do this

```
def my_sum(a, b):
    sum = a + b
    return sum


def main():
    a = int(raw_input("enter a number: "))
    b = int(raw_input("enter a number: ")) 

    sum = my_sum(a,b) 
    print" result: ", sum


main()
```

I hope this will work as per your requirement.
Regards,
Anil

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the purpose of the first function you have defined there (`my_sum`). However, there are a few things wrong in `main` as well. The `return` function always exits the function it is in, and zooms out to a higher level scope. This is very similar to `break`, except that it returns a value as well. Also, your syntax when you ask for user input is incorrect. It should be:

```
def main():
    a = int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))
    b = int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))

    return "Result" + (a+b)

main()
```

Also, if you wanted `my_sum` to automatically return the sum, you should use `return` or `print`:

```
def my_sum(a, b):
    return a + b
```